# Juju SSH setup in orchestra environment

Tags: server, ssh, juju, orchestra

For orchestra, must the public keys be copied to the nodes before 'juju bootstrap' is run for the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David, the nodes don't exist before bootstrap is run. Orchestra configures cobbler to install the nodes from scratch, and then start juju. This is done so that juju charms that are deployed can start with a base, clean system. Its been discussed that we may want to make it easier to take control of an existing machine with juju, but right now that is not how it works.

juju bootstrap basically does this with orchestra:

- Talks to cobbler via the XML-RPC API, finds a system marked for PXE boot that is in the 'available-mgmt-class', injects data to install juju on first boot, and moves it to the 'acquired-mgmt-class'. It then uses the power infastructure, if defined, to turn the machine on. This machine will be the "bootstrap node" which runs zookeeper and the provisioning agent. Included in the "first boot" seed data is the user's SSH public key to install to the 'ubuntu' user so that the juju clients can talk to the bootstrap node over an ssh tunnel.
- Stores an object in the file storage (usually an ssl webdav service on orchestra-provisioning-server) that informs future juju clients that the environment is bootstrapped, and how to contact the bootstrap node.

Note that you can override the ssh authorized keys path to use. It will normally use ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub or ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub. You can also set it with 'authorized-keys-path' in environments.yaml. You can also insert actual keys to override all of that with 'authorized-keys'.

Comment: Some of the lightbulbs have gone on for me with this post. Thank you!
So here's my next question:
If i have a juju zookeeper node set up, what do I have to do in orchestra to deploy juju client nodes as the rest of the machines in my cluster?
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Nothing in orchestra other than add machines that can be pxe booted/installed. Note that since your original post, MaaS has superseded Orchestra. I recommend investigating it, and asking questions about MaaS. :)